# Error Deserializing ScriptObject in Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I have a Silverlight control on an aspx page. A user can choose to select one to many Accounts for filtering some data I'm displaying in the SL control. When they click a button, a "lookup" aspx page is popped open which displays the list of accounts to the user and lets them check the ones they want to include. Then the user clicks "Insert" and that data is passed to the Silverlight control on the opening page.

I ran into one hang-up that is still bugging me. The account lookup page creates an array of Account objects, then passes that to the opening page like this (JavaScript):

```
var accounts = [{ ID: 1, Name: "Foo"}, { ID: 2, Name: "Bar" }]; // test data
if (window.opener && window.opener.accountsInserted) {
  window.opener.accountsInserted(accounts); // pass array of objects to opener
}
```

On the page which opens the pop up window (the same page that hosts the Silverlight control), I'm accepting that array, and passing it to the Silverlight object (JavaScript):

```
function accountsInserted(accounts) {
  silverLightControl.Content.Scriptables.SetAccounts(accounts);
}
```

The code above will error when it tries to call SetAccounts. The managed code within the Silverlight control executes, but it throws an exception like "cannot convert ScriptObject to Account[]" - it's a conversion/casting error. I've attach the debugger and confirmed it's having a problem de-serializing the array of objects passed into the accounts parameter. Here's the managed code which runs (VB .NET in Silverlight control):

```
<ScriptableType()>
Public Class Scriptables

  <ScriptableMember()>
  Public Sub SetAccounts(ByVal accounts As ScriptObject)
    Dim myAccounts As Account() = accounts.ConvertTo(Of Account())() ' this line throws exception
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class Account
  Public Property ID As Integer
  Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

By the way, I am registering in instance of the `Scriptables` as a scriptable object in the Silverlight control: `HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Scriptables", mScriptables)`

Now, before you all start giving me ideas of stuff to try, I've run the gamut. What I've found that works is on the page which hosts the Silverlight control, I copy the `accounts` array to a different array (defined on the page which hosts the Silverlight control), and this actually works:

```
function accountsInserted(accounts) {
  var newAccounts = [];
  if (accounts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++); {
      newAccounts[i] = accounts[i];
    }
  }
  silverLightControl.Content.Scriptables.SetAccounts(newAccounts);
}
```

What is going on here? Why do I have to copy the array to a different array in order for the Silverlight control to be able to de-serialize it properly?

Comment: I don't see any JSON serialization going on here at all. The variable "accounts" has as its value a JavaScript object, **not** JSON. (I'm not trying to be pedantic and rude; I just want to make sure that there's not a very simple mix-up here.)

Comment: ok i will correct my terminology - thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I wonder if the problem has to do with the fact that the object is "born" on a different page.  Internet Explorer has *always* been very picky about that. For example, if you send an object like that from one page to another, and the original page is overwritten by a new page, then touching that old object allocated from the defunct page is likely to trigger an exception.

Comment: i will have to try it out in FireFox to see if it works - maybe it's IE specific.